# Fetching previous hour records in Oracle

Tags: oracle, time, oracle11g, timestamp

I have an usecase where I need to get the previous hour records

Ex: the current time is 1 30 PM and when job runs I need the records between 12PM - 1PM

I tried something like this

```
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  - interval '1' hour ) from table1;
```

But this will yield records from the time it runs

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP               (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-INTERVAL'1'HOUR)
2023-08-17 14:36:39.912 +0530   2023-08-17 13:36:39.912 +0530
```

The requirement is to get the result from

```
Starttime                       Endtime
2023-08-17 12:00:00.000 +0530   2023-08-17 13:00:00.000 +0530
```

even when I run the query at any time between 13-14th hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you'll have to *truncate* boundaries to *hour*.

Setting date/time format, just to know what is what; you don't have to do that.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi';

Session altered.
```

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (id, datum) as
  2    (select 1, to_date('17.08.2023 09:25', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
  3     select 2, to_date('17.08.2023 09:42', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
  4     select 3, to_date('17.08.2023 10:05', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
  5     select 4, to_date('17.08.2023 10:33', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual union all
  6     select 5, to_date('17.08.2023 11:20', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') from dual
  7    )
```

Query:

```
  8  select sysdate, id, datum
  9  from test
 10  where datum >= trunc(sysdate - interval '1' hour, 'hh24')
 11    and datum <  trunc(sysdate, 'hh24');

SYSDATE                  ID DATUM
---------------- ---------- ----------------
17.08.2023 11:26          3 17.08.2023 10:05
17.08.2023 11:26          4 17.08.2023 10:33

SQL>
```

Comment: I told you, you don't have to alter session. I did it just because my default date format is DD-MON-YY (without time component) so I wouldn't be able to illustrate code I posted.